# Unexpected value XXXX imported by the module 'AppModule' in angular2

Tags: angular

Im trying to make a router in Angular2, 
I created an `app.routing.ts` file, which look like that :

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {Routes, RouterModule} from '@angular/router';

import { NewNoteComponent } from './components/new-note.component';
import { NoteListComponent } from './components/note-list.component';


const routes: Routes =[
    {path: '', pathMatch: '', redirectTo: 'note-list'},
    {path: 'note-list', component: NoteListComponent},
    {path: 'new-note', component: NewNoteComponent}
];

NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class AppRoutingModule{}

export const routingComponents = [NewNoteComponent, NoteListComponent];
```

and set my `app.module.ts` like that :

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import {HttpModule} from '@angular/http';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';


import {AppRoutingModule, routingComponents} from './app.routing';
import { SearchComponent} from './components/search.component';


@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule , FormsModule, AppRoutingModule, HttpModule],
  declarations: [ AppComponent,  SearchComponent, NoteListComponent],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})




export class AppModule { }
```

My problem is that when I try to run this thing, it's throw me a weird error 
thats saying that `Unexpected value 'AppRoutingModule' imported by the module 'AppModule'`

That's suppose to be real easy but I really working my mind around what stupid mistake I just did .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `@` inside your `AppRoutingModule` before `NgModule`.

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {Routes, RouterModule} from '@angular/router';

import { NewNoteComponent } from './components/new-note.component';
import { NoteListComponent } from './components/note-list.component';


const routes: Routes =[
    {path: '', pathMatch: '', redirectTo: 'note-list'},
    {path: 'note-list', component: NoteListComponent},
    {path: 'new-note', component: NewNoteComponent}
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class AppRoutingModule{}

export const routingComponents = [NewNoteComponent, NoteListComponent];
```

And you should use `routingComponents` in your `AppModule` `declarations` :

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule , FormsModule, AppRoutingModule, HttpModule],
  declarations: [ AppComponent,  SearchComponent, routingComponents],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: oh my.. thank you! I needed those hawk eyes of yours ;) thanks!